# How to apply combination of multiple functions in R in a smart manner?

Tags: r

Lets assume I have four functions. These are just sample functions. In the real scenario the functions are much more complicated.

```
f1= function(data){
  data1= data*2
  return (data1)
}

f2= function(data){
  data1= data*4
  return (data1)
}

f3= function(data){
  data1= data*data
  return (data1)
}

f4= function(data){
  data1= data**5
  return (data1)
}

data = matrix(1:100,10,10)
```

now I want to apply a combination of all these function and see the output of each

```
f1 then f2
f1 then f3
f1 then f4
... f1 then f2 then f3, 
f1 then f2 then f4.... 
f1 then f2 then f3 then f4.
```

My question is how would I apply a combination of all these functions smartly.

Comment: Are you saying you want to look at all combinations of the applications of these functions?

Comment: Please remove "a tricky issue" from your question title. It's not helpful.

Comment: Yes. I want to look at the combinations of the application of these functions.

Comment: Does order matter to you or do you just care that they get applied

Answer (score 1):

First, I would put your functions in a list

```
ff <- list(f1=f1,f2=f2,f3=f3,f4=f4)
```

then here's a helper function to generate a list of all possible combinations of elements from a list

```
allcomb <- function(x) {
    do.call("c", lapply(seq_along(x), function(n) combn(x,n, simplify=FALSE)))
}
```

Then, you can generate lists of functions that you can pass to `Reduce()` to apply them sequentially to the data (and i've added `setNames()` to identify where each result came from)

```
setNames(
    lapply(
       allcomb(ff),
       function(X) Reduce(function(d,f) f(d), X, init=data)
    ),
    sapply(allcomb(names(ff)), paste, collapse=":")
)
```

Comment: Apparently order matters so you'll also want to look at all permutations of the vectors in the allcomb result.

Comment: This is similar to what I need (I need permutation instead). However, I tried changing combn to permn but it does not work the way I need it to be. This is because perm only gave a permutation of 4 and not the ones less than four. Is there a solution to this?